# Avy copy/delete partial sentence of a certain line

Tags: avy

I have a question about how to implement a command specific to avy.
A template of a command which I would like to generalize is
`avy-kill-ring-save-whole-line`.
I want to be able to copy/delete from char to char on a certain line.

Given some line ..... ------ .....
I want to select the line with avy shortletters notation while being on a different line and then
to copy ------ with avy.
How can I create such a function? I use Doom Emacs on macOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you would like to make a version of `avy-kill-ring-save-whole-line` that kills only a selected part of a line. Starting from `avy-goto-char-timer`, you could achieve it as follows:

```lisp
(defun my-avy-kill-region (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((beg (let ((cands (avy--read-candidates)))
               (car (avy-process cands))))
        (end (let ((cands (avy--read-candidates)))
               (cdr (avy-process cands)))))
    (if arg
        (kill-region beg end)
      (kill-new (buffer-substring beg end)))))
```

or if you prefer to jump to the line first and then select chars on that line like `avy-goto-char`, then starting from `avy-goto-char`/`avy-jump` you could achieve it as follows

```lisp
(defun my-avy-kill-line-region (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (avy--line))
    (let* ((eol (pos-eol))
           (beg (goto-char (car (avy-process (avy--regex-candidates (string (read-char)) (pos-bol) (pos-eol))))))
           (end (cdr (avy-process (avy--regex-candidates (string (read-char)) beg eol)))))
      (if arg
          (kill-region beg end)
        (kill-new (buffer-substring beg end))))))
```

When using this last command, you first, temporarily, jump to some line, and subsequently (type)select a char twice for 'beg' and 'end'.

Both commands you can prepend with a universal-argument (`C-u`) to delete the region instead of copying it (if you prefer to 'swap' this behavior, then swap the clauses in the `if` form).

Comment: @Rareform I have updated the answer with a slightly modified version of your editing suggestion (it is generally preferable to use 'native' functions instead of `evil` functions if possible). Thanks for the suggestion!